# How to avoid any category in foursquare venue search

Tags: iphone, foursquare

I want venues of all categories but "Park". How can I exclude "Park" in my foursquare venue search?
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify through the API a category to exclude. You can, however, in your application strip out all venues who's categories match the park category.

Comment: I guess this is the only way. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `categoryId` (a comma separated list of categories) within your venue search and choose not to include any categories having to do with the types of parks you are talking about. [Foursquare Venue Search Doc](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) You can use this method to exclude just one or multiple categories. Here is a list of the Foursquare categories:

[Foursquare Venue Categories List](https://developer.foursquare.com/categorytree)